# PL/SQL continuous eligibility combine

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a set of data where a member comes in, enrolls into a plan for some time and after completion of his enrollment, if he wishes to continue he can enroll the next day or he can take a break for some time and enroll again, or he can totally terminate.

Sample Data like

```
Member  Start Date  End Date    Eligibility
1   1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
1   1/1/2010    12/31/2010  Y
1   1/1/2011    12/31/2011  Y
1   1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
1   1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
1   1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
2   1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
2   1/1/2010    12/31/2010  Y
2   1/1/2011    12/31/2011  Y
2   1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
2   1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
2   1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
```

I need all the continuous eligibility records to be combined into one single record and need the output like

```
Member  Start Date  End Date    Eligibility
1   1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
1   1/1/2010    12/31/2011  Y
1   1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
1   1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
1   1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
2   1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
2   1/1/2010    12/31/2011  Y
2   1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
2   1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
2   1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
```

Dates may vary for member to member and eligibilities too....

Please let me know the logic to write in PL/SQL

Comment: Can anyone tell me the logic in Sybase IQ or SQL Server for the same question above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
select
    member,
    min(start_date),
    max(end_date),
    eligibility
from
(
    select
        member,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        eligibility,
        min(CONNECT _BY_ROOT (start_date)) AS root_start,
    from
        table
    connect by 
        prior member = member AND
        prior eligibility = eligibility AND
        prior end_date+1 = start_date
    group by
        member, 
        eligibility,
        start_date,
        end_date
) x
group by
    member,
    eligibility,
    root_start
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple (and possible slow) solution.

Select all records that have a matching next record, so you get the records that start a series. Select all records that have a matching previous record, so you get the records that end a series. Join These such that end is after start. Aggregate to find the minimum end date for each start date.

```
select 
  start_dates.member, 
  start_dates.start_date, 
  min(end_dates.end_date) as end_date,
  min(start_dates.eligibility) as eligibility
from
(  
  select * 
  from mytable 
  where exists
  (
    select * 
    from mytable next_date
    where next_date.start_date = mytable.end_date = + 1 
    and next_date.eligibility = mytable.eligibility
  )
) start_dates
join
(  
  select * 
  from mytable 
  where exists
  (
    select * 
    from mytable prev_date
    where prev_date.end_date = mytable.start_date - 1
    and prev_date.eligibility = mytable.eligibility
  )
) end_dates
on start_dates.member = end_dates.member and start_dates.start_date <= end_dates.end_date
group by start_dates.member, start_dates.start_date
order by start_dates.member, start_dates.start_date;
```

A more elegant and probably faster solution should be possible with the use of LAG and LEAD, but I am too lazy right now to figure that out ;-)